# How to present UIViewController without hiding the bottom tabbar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

My application has a bottom tab bar and I want to present a controller without hiding the bottom bar. Since I have to push a controller on the presented controller so I am putting the controller inside the navigation controller. Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to achieve. If anybody has some idea please help me out.

```
guard let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "EmptyWorkout", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogWoroutVC") as? LogWorkoutViewController else { return }
     
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:controller)
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.navigationController?.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You are explicitly covering everything with `. overFullScreen`. If you want to show something while leaving the tab bar visible (and allow interaction with it), create an instance of `LogWorkoutViewController`, add it as a Child View Controller, and add its view to your current controller's view.

Comment: can you please explain with code

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't allow to present a View Controller without hiding Tab Bar.
A workaround is to push your View Controller in the Navigation Stack:

```swift
guard let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "EmptyWorkout", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogWoroutVC") as? LogWorkoutViewController else { return }
     
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: no, my requirement is presenting the screen not push

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very, ***very*** basic example of using `LogWorkoutViewController` as a **child view controller**:

```
class CurrentViewController: UIViewController {

    // assume we have a button in the view controller connected
    //  to this action  
    @IBAction func showTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // load an instance of LogWorkoutViewController
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogWorkoutVC") as? LogWorkoutViewController {
            // add it as a child of self
            addChild(vc)
            // add its view and set constraints
            vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(vc.view)
            let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                // constrain LogWorkoutViewController's view to safe-area
                vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])
            // end of adding child view controller
            vc.didMove(toParent: self)
            
            // set the closure in LogWorkoutViewController so it can
            //  "call back" to self - in this case, we're just removing it
            vc.closeMe = { [weak vc] in
                guard let vc = vc else {
                    return
                }
                vc.willMove(toParent: nil)
                // remove LogWorkoutViewController's view
                vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
                // remove LogWorkoutViewController as a child view controller
                vc.removeFromParent()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
class LogWorkoutViewController: UIViewController {
    // closure to "call back" to parent view controller
    var closeMe: (()->())?
    
    // this would likely be in a button action
    //  for now, touching anywhere (well, touch-end anywhere) will call
    //  the closure
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        closeMe?()
    }
}
```

Comment: where is addChild() is defined?

Comment: Apple Docs for [addChild(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild)